# What type of relationships are these?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm new to nhibernate and i haven't dealt with databases in a long time.

My recipe object:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public virtual int CookTime { get; set; }//in minutes
    public virtual int OvenTemp { get; set; }// in farenhieht
    public virtual IList<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public virtual string Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

my Category object:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my Ingredient object:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual float Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual UnitName Unit { get; set; }

}
```

and my UnitName object:

```
public class UnitName
{
    public virtual string ShortName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LongName { get; set; }
}
```

so my question is what type of relationship is there between recipe and Category/Ingredient?
and between Ingredient and UnitName?

I've read the descriptions of the various types of relationships, but they all seem wrong for some reason.  I know thats not true so there is something i'm not getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a many-to-many relationship: Each recipe has many ingredients / categories, and each category/ingredient has/is in many recipes.

Comment: thanks. is that also the same between the Ingredient and unitName?

Comment: @scott: No; that's a one-to-many relation.  Each ingredient has one unit, but each unit has many ingredients.

Comment: Are you sure? I think relations are reversed in this case. Unlike normal many-to-many.